# Unable to run Hybrid application on remote server MFP 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, remote-server

After migrate the remote server from MFP 6.3.0 to MFP 7.1. I am unable to run the application

MFP 7.1.0.00-20170330-0917

Eclipse Kepler SR 2

Log

```
06-06 12:53:56.233: D/NONE(6221): connectOnStartup
06-06 12:53:56.237: D/NONE(6221): establishSSLClientAuth
06-06 12:53:56.239: D/NONE(6221): establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
06-06 12:53:56.242: D/NONE(6221): Request [/apps/services/api/ITS/android/init]
06-06 12:53:56.243: W/NONE(6221): Note that if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
06-06 12:53:56.967: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(6221): WLUtils.convertStringToJSON in WLUtils.java:495 :: Input string does not contain brackets, or input string is invalid. The string is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221): WLFailResponse.parseErrorFromResponse in WLFailResponse.java:103 :: Additional error information is not available for the current response and response text is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221): org.json.JSONException: Input string does not contain brackets, or input string is invalid. The string is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils.convertStringToJSON(WLUtils.java:496)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLFailResponse.parseErrorFromResponse(WLFailResponse.java:91)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLFailResponse.<init>(WLFailResponse.java:49)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.processFailureResponse(WLRequest.java:745)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:327)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:52)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-06 12:53:56.971: D/wl.certManager(6221): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-06 12:53:56.976: D/wl.certManager(6221): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-06 12:53:56.986: D/wl.request(6221): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request https://server-address/ITS/authorization/v1/clients/instance
06-06 12:53:57.637: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(6221): WLUtils.convertStringToJSON in WLUtils.java:495 :: Input string does not contain brackets, or input string is invalid. The string is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221): WLFailResponse.parseErrorFromResponse in WLFailResponse.java:103 :: Additional error information is not available for the current response and response text is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221): org.json.JSONException: Input string does not contain brackets, or input string is invalid. The string is: Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils.convertStringToJSON(WLUtils.java:496)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLFailResponse.parseErrorFromResponse(WLFailResponse.java:91)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLFailResponse.<init>(WLFailResponse.java:49)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.processFailureResponse(WLRequest.java:745)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:327)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:52)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-06 12:53:57.638: D/wl.failResponse(6221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-06 12:53:57.640: D/wl.certManager(6221): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-06 12:53:57.641: D/NONE(6221): Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":500,"responseText":"Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException\n","errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service is currently not available.","invocationContext":null}
06-06 12:53:57.642: I/chromium(6221): [INFO:CONSOLE(27)] "*******isCustomResponse []", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/PushAppRealmChallengeHandler.js (27)
06-06 12:53:57.645: E/NONE(6221): [/apps/services/api/ITS/android/init] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
06-06 12:53:57.654: E/NONE(6221): Client init failed. The service is currently not available.
```

Any idea how to fix it..???

Answer (score 0):

The log says ""errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service is currently not available."}

Verify your wlclient.properties to see if the hostname, context etc are proper. If so, verify your application logic to see if the relative URI for resources are proper.